# TableViewCell button Border color not visible after updating Xcode 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode8, hidden, visible

It was working fine but after updating to `Xcode8`, `TableViewCell` button's layer circular layer is not visible. But as soon as I scroll table then It is visible. In `Xcode 7.3` it is working fine with scrolling? Seems `Xcode` bug?

Updated:

```
- (CalendarMenuCalendarCell *)configureCalendarCellWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CalendarCell";
    CalendarMenuCalendarCell *calCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // creating cell
    Calendar *cal = self.dataArray[indexPath.row-1];
    calCell.viewType = CalendarViewForCreateEvent;
    calCell.calenarTitle = cal.name;

    if (indexPath != self.selectedIndexPath) {
        calCell.isSelected = NO;
    }else{
        calCell.isSelected = YES;
    }
    return calCell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share any of your code and how the `TableViewCell` is structured? It's very difficult to answer a question without all of the information being provided.

Comment: You're not alone! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578530/since-xcode-8-and-ios10-views-are-not-sized-properly-on-viewdidlayoutsubviews